# Show all files which are indexed by PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I have some huge directories on my hard disk.

I think PyCharm accidentely indexes some of them.

Is there a way to get the list of all directories which are index by
a PyCharm project?

I know that I can use "Mark directory as / Excluded". But I don't want to guess.

I want to know which directories are indexed by PyCharm.

Comment: From what I've read the index can be found on your system, for linux [~/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.2/index](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#142d97d6) you can take a look at the files but there's many of them, some are in binary, so reading them doesn't seem possible. Likely the best chance is [setting up shared indexes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/shared-indexes.html) this allows to freeze the index and export it. But I don't know if that option will give a list of human readable files either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right not a guess [read this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html).

- After that, you know which indexed directories and manage them as you like.